# HTTPRIO connecting to webservice "error : HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" on OS, while working in Win32

Tags: macos, web-services, delphi, firemonkey

I have a simple project that uses the `checkVatService.wsdl` to chek the vality of european VAT numbers.

When running the project on MACOS I the following error : "`error : HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`".

When running on Win32 the project returns "valid"

```
procedure TForm1.ControleVat;
var
  cv  : checkVatApprox;
  cvs : checkVatApproxResponse;
  HTTPRIO1: THTTPRIO;
begin

  HTTPRIO1 := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);

  HTTPRIO1.WSDLLocation := 'checkVatservice.WSDL';
  HTTPRIO1.Service := 'checkVatService';
  HTTPRIO1.Port := 'checkVatPort';

  cvs:=nil;
  cv:=checkVatApprox.Create;
  try
    cv.countryCode := 'BE';
    cv.vatNumber   := '0000000097'; 
    try
      cvs:= ( HTTPRIO1 as checkVatPortType ).checkVatApprox(cv);
      if cvs.valid then begin
        showmessage('valid');
      end else begin
        showmessage('invalid');
      end;
    except
      on e:exception do begin
        showmessage('error : ' + e.Message);
      end;
    end;

  finally
    cv.Free;
    freeandnil(cvs);
  end;
end;
```

The service does not require autohorisation and both in Win32 and OS the username/password are blank.

What is causing this error? What is the difference in connection?

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem, in android.  in windows it's all ok;
it seems related to some strange server issue, if client retrive ipv6 instead ipv4..

i suggest you to use : https://www.isvat.eu/

Comment: I tried this, but it seems like this service is offline atm.